# Can I use jwcrypto to validate a Google generated OAuth2 id_token?

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, oauth, google-authentication

Building on the work in this question: [What is the proper way to validate google granted OAuth tokens in a node.js server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16312784)

Can I use the [jwcrypto](https://github.com/mozilla/jwcrypto) library to validate a Google OAuth2 token in a node.js server? I have the 857 byte token given by Google, which validates using Google's web endpoint at `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?id_token=`. In theory I can use the token plus the Google's certs available [here](https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs) They look like this:

```
{
859c1234d08e008cc261ff11de5f8da1b8c4d490: "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- <stuff> -----END CERTIFICATE----- ",
ad2a50cb70c5da789ee26d05b8f621a99e81202e: "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- <stuff> -----END CERTIFICATE----- "
}
```

So far I've been unable to even load the keys into jwcrypto using the loadPublicKey method. Presumably once I get this working I can call the verify method. Are there any working examples of this online?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just added a new npm modules that decodes and validates Google's id_token.  You can find the code here: https://github.com/gmelika/google-id-token

Usage is fairly straightforward:

```
var googleIdToken = require('google-id-token');
var parser = new googleIdToken({ getKeys: getGoogleCerts });
parser.decode(sampleGoogleIDToken, function(err, token) {
    if(err) {
        console.log("error while parsing the google token: " + err);
    } else {
        console.log("parsed id_token is:\n" + JSON.stringify(token));
    }
});
```

the `getGoogleCerts` function referenced above is a user supplied function that would return the appropriate Google certificate based on the supplied key.  A very basic example of this is:

```
var request = require('request');
function getGoogleCerts(kid, callback) {
    request({uri: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs'}, function(err, response, body){
        if(err && response.statusCode !== 200) {
            err = err || "error while retrieving the google certs";
            console.log(err);
            callback(err, {})
        } else {
            var keys = JSON.parse(body);
            callback(null, keys[kid]);
        }
    });
}
```

Obviously you would want to add caching in there.  Feel free to use your favorite caching mechanism to do that.

Hope that helps.

Comment: How do I know which kid to supply in this getGoogleCerts function?

Comment: what do you mean by add caching there please reply must, i am strucked on this thing ??

Comment: @SudhanshuGaur that's just an optimization, you don't need that to get it to work. but what I meant was that since the certs are good until some time in the future, your `getGoogleCerts` function doesn't need to call the url every time. just cache it in mem

Comment: even if i will put it in mem but i have to call the url man otherwise how would google tell me that token is verified or not ??

Comment: @SudhanshuGaur google doesn't tell you whether a token is verified or not, they give you a public cert that you use to verify the token locally. so you just need to cache the certs

Comment: can you please tell me what code should i write to cache the certs, i have not done caching before this please it will be really helpful :)

Comment: you don't *need* to cache it.  caching is just an optimization.  just use it as is and it'll work

Comment: yes it is working fine but it will be really efficient if i can add caching so please tell me in the code how to use cache, it will be really appreciated ??

Comment: also more thing dont you think as node.js is asynchronous by default so parser.decode can get execute earlier before getting certs from getGoogleCerts so parser will be null most of the cases ?? correct me if i am thinking wrong and please tell me how can i use cache man ??

Comment: @SudhanshuGaur that's why `getGoogleCerts` takes a callback

Comment: hey look at this                                                                                                                                                                                                                                logger.info('time 1: ', "time 1: " + Date.now());
var parser = new googleIdToken({ getKeys: getGoogleCerts });
logger.info('time 2: ', "time 2: " + Date.now());

Comment: function getGoogleCerts(kid, callback) {
    logger.info('time 3: ', "time 3: " + Date.now());
    request({uri: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs'}, function(err, response, body){
        logger.info('time 4: ', "time 4: " + Date.now());
        if(err && response.statusCode !== 200) {
            err = err || "error while retrieving the google certs";
           callback(err, {})
        } else {
            var keys = JSON.parse(body);
            logger.info('time 5: ', "time 5: " + Date.now());
            callback(null, keys[kid]);
        }
    });

Comment: now for above two codes my logger is printing time 1, then time 2 and then time 3 and then time 4 and then time 5 dont you think if parser.decode was executing later than getting googlecerts then time 2 will be printed after time 5 so i think parser.decode you should write inside the callback of gettgooglecerts otherwise parser can be null at parser.decode ??

Comment: @SudhanshuGaur I think you need to read up a bit more about async programming in general, and how nodejs works in particular.

Answer (score 3):

Not likely to work, we haven't tested this use case and our public key formats in jwcrypto are custom right now, waiting for JWK to be fully standardized.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. Do you know of any JS library that might be able to parse Google's format?